# Using WebSockets with Codename One

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, websocket, codenameone

I am new at using Codename One. I am trying to deploy a server that will interact with my app on Amazon Web Services using OpsWorks. The server is going to run on Apache Tomcat and be a dynamic web project written in Java, and I am wondering the best way to communicate with the Codename One client. I am planning to use the Socket classes provided by Codename One, but and not sure what to use for the server-side code. Will it work to use WebSockets from Apache? I am having difficulty debugging the server code and have hit a wall here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets aren't compatible with sockets so you will need to code a websocket implementation which is a bit of work. I suggest you use HTTP communication which is more portable and very performant on the devices.

You can also use solutions such as [PubNub](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/11/fast-push-communication-using-pubnub.html) which allow for fast message based communications.